# COM CORBA Support in Julia-Lang

Tags: com, julia, corba

I am working on a Material Property Package in Julia, for a Property Package to become a standard one is mandatory that implements different COM | CORBA interfaces for each component ([CAPE-OPEN standards](http://www.colan.org/index-3.html)). Is it possible to implement such interfaces in Julia-Lang?

EXAMPLE CODE

```
type MaterialObject
  .
  .
  module ICapeCorbaInterface
end

runserver(materialobject)
```

Comment: Using CORBA from Julia will require that there is a CORBA implementation for Julia, as far as I know that doesn't exist. A first step would be to create an IDL to Julia language mapping and as second step to create an implementation for that, all together a significant amount of work.